# How do I run a ruby function inside an ActiveRecord query?

Tags: ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

`City.all.sample{rand(1..3)}` I want the random function to generate the sample count. This always returns one record.

Comment: @iGian couple of hundred times. Less than a thousand.

Comment: `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7].sample(rand(1..3))`

Comment: @iGian that was super simple! Thanks.

Comment: `sample` is not an active record query, though.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I meant `City.all` being a query

Comment: @tambakoo: that it is, but you are not passing your logic to it. It runs unaltered. And then `sample` acts on the results. And in general, you can't "pass a ruby function to be used in a query". That's the whole point of the databases: to filter/sort/return data with maximum efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest this way, to avoid retrieving all records:

```
n.times.map.with_object([]) { |_, a| a << City.find(City.ids.sample) }
```

It returns an array of records.

Of course, `n` can be a random integer.

Comment: Why not `City.order('RAND()').limit(rand(1..3))`? (`RAND()`, `RANDOM()`) depending the DB.